# How to select (copy) an output in terminal without mouse

Tags: command-line, mouse, copy-and-paste

It seems like a typical way that you have some output in the terminal and if you want to select certain phrase you use your mouse to copy it, but is there any way to select without using mouse? For example, I input `ls`, and get a list of files, and I want to select the second file (second row), is there a way to copy the name without using mouse?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91863/terminal-copy-from-cli-without-using-mouse

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Using tmux:

I use `tmux` in vi mode:

1. Go to copy mode (in my config <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>escape</kbd>, Default Prefix is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>)

   - In config file (`~/.tmux.conf`): `bind Escape copy-mode`
2. Move around (Using arrows)
3. Select your desire output (Start selection with <kbd>Space</kbd>)

   - In my config <kbd>v</kbd>: `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X begin-selection`
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy the text.

   - In my config <kbd>y</kbd>: `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection`
5. Press <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to Paste.

[image]

Also create a key binding like this:

```
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xsel -bi"
```

So you can save the buffer into system clipboard by pressing <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

I have add my configuration cause it's more like vim than default config.

---

#### Using commands:

Here is what I do:

1. Run the command (eg: `ls -1`)
2. Process the output to get my desired result
3. Pip it to `xsel -bi`

In your example:

```
$ ls -1 | sed -n 2p | xsel -bi
```

- `ls -1` prints the outputs each in one line
- `sed -n 2p` get the second line
- `xsel` has been used to copy the final result in clipboard.

If the command takes too long to run, first save the output to a file the process the output:

```
command > output
head -10 output | whatever | xsel -bi
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common Linux terminals emulators cannot do this directly. There a 2 ones I am aware of, though.

One which exists for quite some time is Termite. It is rather spartanic, though (keyboard shortcuts not configurable, no multiple tabs).

Now there is a second one, which has these features named Mantid (which I' shamelessly advertising here :) ):

https://github.com/omgold/mantid-term

There isn't an Ubuntu build, yet, though, one Arch and RPM. You might try to build an RPM and convert to to deb using Alien, though.

Comment: I would like to try `mantid`, but I can not find any tutorial or manual. Is there any documentation out there? It would be good to know at least how it accomplishes the functionality requested in the question.

Comment: There is a manpage ('man mantid') and there are example configuration files in /usr/share/mantid. The manpage mostly documents the configuration options, and the active keybindings can be looked up in the config file.